# Скрытое консольное приложение меняет курсор

Tags: c#, cursor, консоль

Сделал простое консольное приложение. В свойствах проекта поменял тип приложения на **Приложение Windows** - таким образом приложение открывается скрытым.

Однако, при запуске приложения курсор мышки в Windows меняется на **занятый**:

[image: Курсор]

В методе Main ничего особенного. В методе DoWork работают методы по очистке ненужных файлов

```
static void Main()
{
    var processes = Process.GetProcessesByName("mpCleaner");
    if (processes.Length > 1)
        Environment.Exit(0);
    DoWork();
}

private static void DoWork()
{
    try
    {
        Thread.Sleep(5000);
        RemoveOldFunctions();
        RemoveUnsupportedAutocadFunctions();
        RemoveDllsFromTopDirectory();
        RemovePendingOverwriteFiles();
        RemoveOldDlls();
        RemoveAutocadFunctionsIfHasItInSubdirectory();
    }
    catch
    {
        //
    }
    finally
    {
        Environment.Exit(0);
    }
}
```

Есть ли возможность убрать смену курсора? Делать службу предлагать не надо

Comment: Делайте `PeekMessage` и `GetMessage` что бы винда увидела, что процесс её "слышит", иначе она считает что повис (это главный стержень ProcessMessages). UDP Ой, да на c# это скорее всего так http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34613362/what-does-application-processmessage-do

Comment: @nick_n_a, там написано, что аналог на .NET - Application.DoEvents(). Но я уже пробовал - не помогает

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проверил - вроде работает, колесико уходит почти сразу.

```
using System.Threading;
using System.Windows.Forms;

public class Demo {


static void Main() {

bool Working = true;
new Thread(() => {
   Thread.Sleep(20000);
   //  Вписать код вашей програмы
   Working = false;
}).Start();

while (Working) {
    Application.DoEvents();
    Thread.Sleep(500);
     }
   }
}
```

P.S. Не хватает развечто try-catch.

Нужно что б вызов `PeekMessage`(без ожидания) и `GetMessage` (с чисткой сообщений) происходил регулярно, не реже раз в секунду, для того что бы винда видела, что процесс её "слышит", иначе она считает что GUI повис (это главный стержень `ProcessMessages` в c# аналог `Application.DoEvents().` ). А, да, если ваше приложение не консольное то.... оно GUI. (варианты Консольное, GUI, Служба, Драйвер - думаю всё перечислил).

Comment: Да, так стало гораздо лучше. Однако иконка "зависания" все-равно появляется при запуске приложения. Только теперь на одну секунду. Видимо этого не избежать

Comment: Есть ещё приклол c# от "microsoft" - время между запуском exe, и передачей управления `Мain` может составлять от 1 до 10-20 секунд. (раньше я думал что запускается сразу). У меня 1-й запуск - где-то 10 сек висят "часики", а потом, 2,3-й запуски - по 1-2 сек. Если переписать на с++ - будет быстрее;)